# Magento Exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9

What is the problem to the code? I cannot upload to database. It comes the message.This error occur when i include category to advanced search.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND (a_81.value IN('44')) AND ( e.website_id = '1' ) AND ( e.customer_group_id =' at line 4

#0 /lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#4 /lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#5 /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(811): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Price.php(280): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchPairs(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php(158): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Price->getCount(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price), 100)
#8 /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php(115): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->getRangeItemCounts(100)
#9 /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php(314): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->getPriceRange()
#10 /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(153): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->_getItemsData()
#11 /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(122): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->_initItems()
#12 /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(109): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItems()
#13 /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#14 /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php(220): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#15 /app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml(45): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View->canShowOptions()
#16 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/mnt/house/loui...')
#17 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/ultimo...')
#18 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#19 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#20 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#22 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#24 /app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#25 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/mnt/house/loui...')
#26 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/ultimo...')
#27 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#28 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#29 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#30 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#31 /app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/AdvancedController.php(58): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#32 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_CatalogSearch_AdvancedController->resultAction()
#33 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('result')
#34 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#35 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#36 /app/Mage.php(685): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#37 /index.php(92): Mage::run('', 'store')
#38 {main}
```

Any help please? I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: could you add your code

Comment: here i use code in this. https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/display/m1wiki/How+to+Add+Search+By+Category+to+Advanced+Search